# Any method to avoid creating individual files when using groupby and sortvalues in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

this is a small part of my dataset which contains thousands of rows

```
designation   names                  runs   wickets catches
batsman       brendon mccullum        78       0       12
bowler        shane bond              0        3       0   
bowler        mitchell mcclenaghan    20       1       1 
batsman       kane williamson         192      0       7
wicketkeeper  brendon mccullum        78       0       12
batsman       daniel vettori          65       11      3
wicketkeeper  luke ronchi             7        0       4
bowler        daniel vettori          65       11      3
batsman       martin guptill          120      0       2
```

I need to split the dataset based on names, calculate the weightage for each column and then append to same excel sheet. this is my code

```
df1 = df.sort_values('names')
for i, g in df1.groupby('names'):
    g.to_csv('{}'.format(i) + '-names'+ '.csv', header=True, index_label=True)
```

This code splits the main file into intermediate files for each name and then I run a for loop to perform the calculation on all intermediate files.

```
filenames = glob.glob('*-names.csv')

    for files_ in filenames:
        df2 = pd.read_csv(files_)


        ### perform required calculations


        df.to_excel(writer, 'Sheet1', index=False, header=True)
        writer.save()
```

This code is working for me but it creates huge number of intermediate files. I was wondering if there is any method that bypasses that file creation step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you need processes each group and then write to excel:

```
df1 = df.sort_values('names')
for i, g in df1.groupby('names'):
    print (g)
    # perform required calculations with g
    g.to_excel(writer, 'Sheet1', index=False, header=True)
    writer.save()
```

Or maybe need apply for each group custom function:

```
def f(x):
    print (x)
    # perform required calculations with x
    return x

df2 = df1.groupby('names').apply(f)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Need to change a few things before running this code. I'll try the code and see what it returns.

Comment: Thanks! The second method works for me. Because I am using pd.merge with another dataframe, the first method is not returning merged df when I use g.

Comment: Super, glad can help!